# How to find all occurrences of multiple elements in a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list:

```
['a','b','b','c']
```

to find all occurrences of an element I use:

```
incd=['a','b','b','c']
indeces=[i for i, x in enumerate(incd) if x == 'b']
```

how can I search for two elements and all their positions?

```
w1='a'
w2='b'
indeces=[i for i, x in enumerate(incd) if x == w1|w2]
```

returns

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

and

```
indeces=[i for i, x in enumerate(incd) if x == 'a|b']
```

returns

```
[]
```

both fails

I would like to have returned

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Why is `pandas` tagged in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do that: you have to use the condition 'or'

```
incd = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
w1 = 'a'
w2 = 'b'
indeces = [i for i, x in enumerate(incd) if x == w1 or x== w2]
```

if you have lot of data to test: use a list

```
w = ['a', 'b' ,'d',...]
indeces = [i for i, x in enumerate(incd) if x in w]
```

Comment: what if I go up to w7? It will be a long statement

Answer (score 4):

IIUC,

```
s=pd.Series(incd)
s[s.eq(w1)|s.eq(w2)].index
#Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest going through the [Operators in Python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm).

**Replace this**:

```
if x == w1|w2
```

**With this**:

```
if x == w1 or x == w2
```

enumerate over the list, and check if the element is equal to `w1` or `w2`:

```
s = ['a','b','b','c']

w1 = 'a'
w2 = 'b'

for indx, elem in enumerate(s):
   if elem == w1 or elem == w2:
      print("Elem: {} at Index {}".format(elem, indx))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Elem: a at Index 0
Elem: b at Index 1
Elem: b at Index 2
```

**Shorter-version**:

```
print([i for i, e in enumerate(s) if e == w1 or e == w2])   # to have a tuple of both elem and indx replace i with (e,i)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: love the explanation

Comment: @alex Thank you! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you tag pandas

```
l=['a','b','b','c']

s=pd.Series(range(len(l)),index=l)
s.get(['a','b'])
Out[893]: 
a    0
b    1
b    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `set` for more speed and a dynamic number of elements to search for:

```
find = {2, 3} # The elements we want to find
a = [1,2,2,3,4] # our list
x = [ind for ind, val in enumerate(a) if val in find]
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` operator to expression logical OR relation.

```py
incd = list('abcd')
w1, w2 = 'a', 'b'

indeces = [i for i, x in enumerate(incd) if x in [w1, w2]]
```

It results correct indeces as desired

```py
indeces = [0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
indeces=[i for i, x in enumerate(incd) if x == w1 or x == w2]
```

Comment: Hi, please add some explanation to why this is a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a `defaultdict` with list as its default

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for n,e in enumerate(incd): 
    d[e].append(n)
```

What's in d at this point?

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [0], 'b': [1, 2], 'c': [3]})
```

and to get positions of 'a' or 'b' (and prove it works for a key `'foo'` not in `incd`)

```
print( d['a']+d['b']+d['foo'] )
# gives [0,1,2]
```